# UISearch Bar query in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I am making Map application and I have already able to call web service which show Shops location on map with annotation. My web service contain more than 200 shops in Australia. I am taking one UISearch bar in which when I insert Syd.....then Sydney, Australia kind  of addresses autofill tableview should open. How can I achieve this.. Do I need to call web service Url again for address autofill tablview or Should I insert manually address or is there any method???

Edited:=
In my application I am searching shops location within 5,10,15Km of radius. And if user want another location instead of current location then he can insert his any location to find shops information around that inserted location. So when user insert his location then autofill address tableview should open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution can be to keep the predefined values in database (Core Data) and then on textDidChange delegate of searchBar you can query the database to search for a list if data matching the current serach keyword. The results thus produced can be shown in a table view with some animation effect so as to give the feel of auto suggest.

Calling the webservice on textDidChange will block the User Interface and will not be good option to proceed with. though this feature is more prevalent on web but on device I find the first choice more productive than the second one.

**EDIT: Answer for problem being asked in edit part of question**

1. You need to put an auto suggest.
2. Fetch data from Server (using web service).

Now to provide functionality of address suggestion like "Syd" turning into Sydney, Australia , my above answer will help you to put these static addresses in database and then providing user with auto suggest options.  For the second part you can save the lat/long of the places in database and once user finalize his selection you can query the webservice to get you the data.

The steps can be summarized as ..

- User Types Syd.
- You query database to search for place which match Syd using some query such as place LIKE %syd%.
- Populate the table with autosuggest with showing place name like 
  Sydney,Australia.
- User selects a place , correspondingly you pick the Lat/long (fetched
  along with the names in above query)and query your web service to
  fetch you data for

**Place** = Sydny, Australia (Not really Required)
**Latitude** = SOME VALE for Sydney 
**Longitude** - SOME VALUE for Sydney
**Radius** = 5,10,15 depending upon your application logic

Server will then fetch you all shops in given range for particular Lat/long.

More calculation intensive work can be done at server's end and at client's end less web service calls should be made to avoid latency.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same app which was showing addresses of persons so I was using a webservice which was giving me all the addresses and I was keeping them in NSMutableArray and then I was checking the string in array in textDidChange function of UISearchBar and if there is any string matching the prefix then I was showing the address in UISearchBar...But in this case if you wrote only 'S' then it will return more than one record so there you need to decide according to client's requirement how to show, does he wants list or any matching record...If list is expected then you need to show the tableview and when user picks the value then just hide the tableview.....

Comment: In my application I am searching shops location within 5,10,15Km of radius. And if user want another location instead of current location then he can insert his any location to find shops information around that inserted location. So when user insert his location then autofill address tableview should open......

Comment: Make a webservice such that it will take your current location/ location set by the user and pass its lattitude, longitude and vicinity(5km/10km) and get the data...

Comment: right now I am in Mumbai and setting radius 8000Km i am able to get shops location in  Australia on single button from current location mumbai. Now I want to insert sydney location in UISearch bar which will open similer sydney address autofill in tableview. On selecting that location I want to search shops around sydney.......